# Uncaught TypeError at WebSocket.ws.onmessage

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm new to web socket and I'm trying to get my feet wet by trying out the code below.

```
var id=0; 
var symbol=""; 
var interval=""; 
var open_time=0; 
var open=0; 
var high=0; 
var low=0; 
var close=0; 

var ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.bybit.com/realtime');

ws.onopen = function(){
    //console.log("Socket has been opened!");
    ws.send('{"op":"subscribe","args":["kline.BTCUSD.1m"]}');
}

ws.onmessage = function(msg){
    //console.log(msg.data);        

    var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    //console.log(obj.data);

    id = obj.data.id;
    symbol = obj.data.symbol;
    interval = obj.data.interval;
    open_time = new Date(obj.data.open_time * 1000);
    open = obj.data.open;
    high = obj.data.high;
    low = obj.data.low;
    close = obj.data.close;

}
```

And although the code above works just fine, but I still can't figure out the error in console log below:

```
main.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (main.js:28)
```

I hope somebody can give me an idea why the `onmessage` function `cannot read the property "id" of undefined` on the first iteration but no problem reading it on the succeeding loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error in this statement `id = obj.data.id;`

Here, you are trying to access `id` property of `data`. But `data` is `undefined` and that is the reason for that error.

You are getting `data` from `msg`, which is sent from a socket connection. Make sure you are sending appropriate `msg` value the first time.

This is the explanation for that error. If you can post the code where you are sending data to this function, we can find out how to fix that error.

**EDIT:**

Looks like you are receiving data from some other third-party server. If you can run below code you can see the first message you are receiving.

**First message:**

```
{"success":true,"ret_msg":"","conn_id":"b75dcae2-48e6-4283-8922-3799a199d8c8",
"request":{"op":"subscribe","args":["kline.BTCUSD.1m"]}}
```

[image]

As you can see this first message doesn't have `data` property. And when you try to access it you are getting that error.

`data` property is present from second message onwards, so you are not getting any error on succeeding messages.

**Second message:**

```
{ "topic":"kline.BTCUSD.1m",
   "data":{
      "id":0,"symbol":"BTCUSD", "open_time":1567828500,"open":10349,
      "high":10349.5,"low":10349,"close":10349.5,"volume":420020,
      "turnover":40.58444293000001,"interval":"1m"
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.bybit.com/realtime');

ws.onopen = function() {
  //console.log("Socket has been opened!");
  ws.send('{"op":"subscribe","args":["kline.BTCUSD.1m"]}');
}

messages = [];

ws.onmessage = function(msg) {

  messages.push(msg.data);
  console.log(messages[0]);
}
```

You can check if the `data` property is not `undefined` or `null` before accessing it.

```
ws.onmessage = function(msg) {

  if(msg && msg.data) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);

    if(obj && obj.data) {           
      id = obj.data.id;
      symbol = obj.data.symbol;
      interval = obj.data.interval;
      open_time = new Date(obj.data.open_time * 1000);
      open = obj.data.open;
      high = obj.data.high;
      low = obj.data.low;
      close = obj.data.close;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Nikhil, I am sending that data to a page using jquery like so $('.id').text(id);

Comment: @anagnam - Check out my edited answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I think I will just have to wrap it in a conditional statement to avoid getting error

Comment: That's right @anagnam. You can have a conditional statement to check if `data` exists before performing any operations on it. Also, first message looks like an acknowledgment message which you can safely ignore.

Comment: thank you Nikhil, I think I can pick it from here. thanks again for the heads up.

Comment: That's great @anagnam. Happy to help!

Comment: @anagnam - For the benefit of future users, consider marking the answer as accepted if it has answered your question.

Comment: sure @Nikhil but before I accept your answer, can you please edit and post your take on my issue? basically, I just want to get the value of the `data` object like the  `id` for example. thanks